# Android navigation component with `android.intent.action`

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I want to implement the `android.intent.action.SEND` as per the [developers tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive) with the [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started).

But when making deep links in the `navigation.xml` it requires a `Uri` with the below error message:

> Navigation XML document  element must contain a app:uri
> attribute.

I am using Android Studio 4.1.3 and I do have the option to choose an action. But it just doesn't work without `uri`.

[The docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit) are leaving some basic questions open:

1. How to get the intent params like `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`
2. How to provide `category` and 'data'?
3. How to provide multiple actions/categories/datas?

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake 4.1.3

Comment: If you're using [Navigation 2.3](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.3.0) or higher, the visual editor should allow you to set either an action, mime type, or URI. Can you include a screenshot of the dialog screen you see when you add a deep link in the Navigation Editor?

Comment: @ianhanniballake: FWIW, [the Navigation documentation implies that a `Uri` is required](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit), at least by my reading of it.

Comment: @CommonsWare - it depends which documentation you read, as [this Navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#uri) was updated to say that implicit deep links support actions, mime types, and/or URIs, aligning it with the Navigation 2.3 release notes.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: OK, good to know! I filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185662361 for trying to get that other page updated to reflect this change, since I didn't see an existing issue for it.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for your feedback. I updated the question to demonstrate the problem better.